# How to build a regex for a whole word match for all languages in cpp?

Tags: c++, regex

Will the `\b` regex for word boundary work in cpp for all languages? Or is it just latin alphabet?

If not - how would one match a whole word such as "תפוח"?

Specifically I thought about something like this`[^\s]תפוח[$\s]` but not sure if `^` is interpeted as negation or start of string here...

I'm using the PCRE library.

Comment: Regex is not a C++ feature. So it depends on which library you are using for regex. Text encoding will be more important.

Comment: Inside a character class, `$` is a literal `$` and `^` a literal `^`, unless it's the first character in which case this becomes a negative character class: you'll need `(?:\s|^)`

Comment: Word segmentation is a huge problem in languages such as Chinese, Japanese, Sanskrt, and others, that is not solvable via regular expressions, and only semisolvable using other methods.

Comment: @Almo What about `std::regex`?  It's part of the standard library (but only since C++11, so your compiler may not support it yet).

Comment: @Robin your comment helped a lot. And I also found this cool site http://regexr.com/ which clarified the meaning of this pattern.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. My personal favorite is http://regex101.com/, but whatever floats your regex boat :) FYI if you need to push deeper, there are lots of resources in this StackOverflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what regex engine you are using. But anyway you might like to consider using [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), because it has a wrapper which can be used with the ICU library for handling unicode.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/intro.html) for this says you can:

> Create regular expressions that support various Unicode data
>   properties, including character classification.

This implies /b and /B should work with any encoding supported by ICU.

In the 'standards' section for Unicode compliance it says:

> 1.4 Simple Word Boundaries: Conforming: non-spacing marks are included in the set of word characters.